# Can we filter the data from exact data not from filtered data?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

In my project  had a  kendo grid with filtering, filtering is working fine,but data is not clearing dynamically while filter is cleared. filter data is cleared by button click how to clear without "clear" button click.My grid code is

```
         var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: {
                       type  : "odata",
            transport      : {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema         : {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        OrderID  : { type: "number" },
                        Freight  : { type: "number" },
                        ShipName : { type: "string" },
                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                        ShipCity : { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize       : 10
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable  : true,
        pageable  : true,
        columns   : [
            {
                field     : "OrderID",
                filterable: false
            },
            "Freight",
            {
                field : "OrderDate",
                title : "Order Date",
                width : 100,
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
            },
            {
                field: "ShipName",
                title: "Ship Name",
                width: 200
            },
            {
                field: "ShipCity",
                title: "Ship City"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: It is not getting clear what you ask, put a better description.

Comment: I mean for example column shipname:xyz entered for filtering xyz values in shipname column in the kendogrid,it filters the xyz values in shipname.If we need another filter ie.,abc values from shipname name column,it filters the abc values without using clear button .it works fine.But if I filter another column ex:shipID it was not clearing the previous filtered values of shipname column without using clear button in the filter widget.I want to clear all the previous filters dynamically before I am going filter another column.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to use the [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function) function (when type is 'read') to get rid of the filters that you do not need and always send only the last item of filters array.

Comment: ya m trying that one but grid is  displaying nothing,here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/15/